# Invalid hook call which I can't seem to fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs

title pretty much says it, I've looked at some examples, but none of the fixes really worked for me. I understand it's the const, moving it  within the class and out of the export, no luck. Can't seem to get it working. Anyone got any ideas? Thank you.

I get the error below at the line `const [ws, setWs] = useState();`

"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

```js
export default function PlayerHoc(ComposedComponent) {
  const [ws, setWs] = useState();
  const [roomIp, setRoomIp] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const wsUrl =
      process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"
        ? "ws://localhost:8888"
        : "ws://" + roomIp;
    setWs(new WebSocket(wsUrl));
  }, [roomIp]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ws) return;
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send("PlaybackRequest");
    };
  }, [ws]);


  class PlayerHoc extends Component {
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return nextProps.playing || (this.props.playing && !nextProps.playing);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.currentSong.id !== this.props.currentSong.id) {
        const id = this.props.currentSong.id;
        const other = this.props.currentSong.linked_from
          ? this.props.currentSong.linked_from.id
          : null;
        this.props.containsCurrentSong(other ? `${id},${other}` : id);
      }
    }

    render = () => (
      <ComposedComponent
        {...this.props}
        playContext={(context, offset) => this.props.playSong(context, offset)}
        playSong={() => this.props.playSong()}
        {...setRoomIp(this.props.roomIp)}
      />
    );
  }
//testbug
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      currentSong: state.playerReducer.status
        ? state.playerReducer.status.track_window.current_track
        : {},
      contains: state.libraryReducer.containsCurrent ? true : false,
      trackPosition: state.playerReducer.status
        ? state.playerReducer.status.position
        : 0,
      playing: state.playerReducer.status
        ? !state.playerReducer.status.paused
        : false
    };
  };


  function nextSong(skip) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "skipSong", data: skip }))
  }
  function previousSong(prev) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "previousSong", data: prev }))
  }
  function pauseSong(pause) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "pauseSong", data: pause }))
  }
  function playSong(play) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "playSong", data: play }))
  }
  function seekSong(seek) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "seekSong", data: seek }))
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators(
      {
        nextSong,
        previousSong,
        pauseSong,
        playSong,
        seekSong,

      },
      dispatch
    );
  };

   return connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(PlayerHoc);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a Functional Component `PlayerHoc`, and a class `PlayerHoc`,

Comment: This code is....bizarre. You shouldn't be defining components INSIDE other components. Also, hooks can *only* be used inside components or inside other hooks. This is neither. This is just a regular function which *returns* a connected component.

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to make an HoC, but he's calling hooks inside the HoC itself (rules of hook prevent calling them outside of an actual function component).

Comment: So with my HoC I wouldn't be able to call a hook? I'd have to do it outside? How would I be able to send props through to my HoC?

Comment: Honestly, you don't need hooks at all. Just put everything in the class component you're creating to wrap the `ComposedComponent`, so `useEffect` would just be within the `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` methods.

Comment: With the useEffect inside componentDidUpdate, I get that ws & roomIP isn't defined cause I'm not using the hooks.

Comment: Not the `useEffect` itself, just the logic.

Comment: ```if (!ws) return```  seems to be the problem, calling effect by condition is not allowed. Try to comment out see if the same problem appear. Also, as pointed out before, declare a class inside the functional component seems to be a new implementation to me, maybe you can try separating into two different components?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01this is not a function component, it's an HoC (attempt) with misplaced hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a mess. But let's try to refactor this into a working Higher Order Component.

There are several issues here, but the main ones are:

- Defining a class component inside of a functional component
- Improper use of hooks.

So lets start by defining a normal Higher Order Component. Lets call it withPlayer.

withPlayer is going to return a Class component.

Inside this class component we can do things like create a websocket, and build all of your player controls.

Then we can pass those player controls as props to the Wrapped Component.

Finally, our default export will apply our redux connect HOC. We can use the compose function from redux, to compose both withPlayer and connect onto our Wrapped Component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';

function withPlayer(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      const wsUrl =
        process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? 'ws://localhost:8888' : 'ws://' + props.roomIp;

      this.ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return nextProps.playing || (this.props.playing && !nextProps.playing);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.currentSong.id !== this.props.currentSong.id) {
        const id = this.props.currentSong.id;
        const other = this.props.currentSong.linked_from
          ? this.props.currentSong.linked_from.id
          : null;
        this.props.containsCurrentSong(other ? `${id},${other}` : id);
      }
    }

    nextSong = (skip) => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'skipSong', data: skip }));
    };

    previousSong = (prev) => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'previousSong', data: prev }));
    };

    pauseSong = (pause) => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'pauseSong', data: pause }));
    };

    playSong = (play) => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'playSong', data: play }));
    };

    seekSong = (seek) => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'seekSong', data: seek }));
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          playContext={(context, offset) => this.playSong(context, offset)}
          nextSong={this.nextSong}
          previousSong={this.previousSong}
          pauseSong={this.pauseSong}
          playSong={this.playSong}
          seekSong={this.seekSong}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentSong: state.playerReducer.status
      ? state.playerReducer.status.track_window.current_track
      : {},
    contains: state.libraryReducer.containsCurrent ? true : false,
    trackPosition: state.playerReducer.status ? state.playerReducer.status.position : 0,
    playing: state.playerReducer.status ? !state.playerReducer.status.paused : false,
  };
};

export default compose(withPlayer, connect(mapStateToProps));
```

This is how you would use it

```js
import withPlayer from './withPlayer'

const MyComponent = props => {
  return <>You're Player wrapped component</>
}

export default withPlayer(Mycomponent);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've tried this and get the error "Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined" 

at line 10, contructor(props)
 function withPlayer(WrappedComponent) {
   9 |   return class extends Component {
> 10 |     constructor(props) {

Comment: @wasntme did you import React and Component? `import React, { Component } from "react";`

Comment: Yep, got these ```javascript import  { React, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
```

Comment: @wasntme I've updated my code snippet to include the imports.

Comment: @wasntme I see in your comment, that you've incorrectly imported React.

Comment: @wasntme it should be `import React, { Component } from 'react';` That is why createElement is called on undefined.

Comment: yup thats my fault lol sorry. worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228500/discussion-between-wasnt-me-and-benjamin).